# Composition between abstract classes

Tags: c++, abstract, composition

Is it possible to build a relationship of composition (not aggregation) between two abstract classes?

I don't think so because I cannot instantiate an abstract class. But maybe there's a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
class A
{
    virtual ~A() = 0;
};


class B
{
    virtual ~B() = 0;
    A* mA;
};
```

You are allowed to have pointers to abstract types.

Comment: Isn't it an aggregation between A and B? Doesn't mA live outside B? To create the responsibility of mA's lifetime regards B, i should put B::~B{delete mA;} ...is it correct? (so virtual ~B() and not virtual ~B() = 0)

Comment: Not necesarilly. Responsibility is a logic thing. You don't have to create mA inside B. You can assign it from outside and delegate responsibility to destroy it to something outside the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pointer or reference to the other class. For example:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void m() = 0;
  virtual ~A() { }
};

class B {
public:
  virtual void m() = 0;
  virtual ~A() { }

private:
  boost::scoped_ptr<A> a;
};
```

In C++11 you can use `std::unique_ptr` instead. Note that this makes `B` noncopyable—that is somewhat common for classes using subtype polymorphism.

Comment: You declared a as private member; Since B is abstract, Wouldn't it rather to declare it as protected?